# Can I show admob ads on wordpress android app?

Tags: android, webview, admob

I have developed simple webview app for my website. App simply load url of my website with in webview. Is it ok to insert adview for admob ads in this type of app? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't be okay? It's your website and your app.

Comment: hey thanks for reply..Some where i read that for web apps you should use adsense? Sir, I havn't found admob sdk. Please guid where to get it. Thanks..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about policy of google play store instead of a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either embed the ad in your webpage or add an adview to your app layout. It's really up to your personal preference.

I suppose the big difference is that if you wanted to change the adview after you've published the app, you would have to release an update while if your ad was on the webpage you could just change it there.

You should also consider that if you have ads on the webpage for people viewing it through a browser, you probably don't want to have additional ads within the app itself (or maybe you do, I don't know), it all depends on how your users access this website.

Comment: please let me know about new admob sdk. There is no new admob sdk available.

Comment: i can't find admob sdk? sir,where i download admob sdk? Google say's no standalone sdk for admob but it is integrated with google play services.

Comment: Yeah. You need to import the google_play_services into eclipse or whatever you are using and add it as a library to your app project. It is EXTREMELY well documented as pretty much every single app uses it so I'm not going to explain it. Just google it.